# any way to make the name show up on the select from in mysql instead of the index number?

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause

im making a database for a college project in mysql workbench, as one of the requisitions my teacher asked to make it so that i can select the patients from a medical consultation that did the test for Covid19, currently my code to do it is like this:

`SELECT Paciente FROM consulta WHERE Diagnostico='Covid19'`

however this only shows the index numbers of said patients, i wanted a code that could show up the actual names and surnames on their tables, is there any way to do it?

Edit: sorry i didnt give this info initially, but the name and surname im trying to reach are on another table called "paciente" of which this "Paciente" above is a foreign key of

Comment: You definitely need to add some info about *structure* of your database

Comment: my mistake, basically there is a table called "paciente" where the data from the patients are, the name and surname im interested on showing, this "P:aciente" on the code above is a foreign key on the table "consulta" to that table

Comment: If required data is in another table, you probably need a **join**. This site is a rich place when it comes to answers, help yourself to explore it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Paciente field probably only contains the ID. You should replace it to * to show every field and after that replace * with only the fields you want. In this case Name and Surname.

Comment: the name and surname are not on the consulta table, they are on the paciente table of which this paciente is an foreign key to, can i still call the name and surname by selecting from consulta?

Comment: You will need to Join your consulta table and your paciente table in order to select your name and surname with the consulta table.